# Proper use of Spring's ResolvableType to determine generic type

Tags: spring, generics, types

I'm attempting to use Spring's `org.springframework.core.ResolvableType` to figure out the parameterized type at runtime as such:

```
public class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
    private final Class<T> typeClass;

    public CustomStateSerializer() {
        ResolvableType type = ResolvableType.forClass(getClass());
        ResolvableType genericType = type.getGeneric();
        this.typeClass= (Class<T>) genericType.resolve();
    }
}

...

new MyClass<MyType>();
```

Unfortunately, `genericType` results to `?`. Clearly I'm not using it correctly and I can't seem to find any good docs for the solution.

Answer (score -1):

The class is only has reference to  which is not defined yet. So you can pass the instance that will have an specific  already:

```
    ResolvableType type = ResolvableType.forClass(getClass(), this);
    this.typeClass = type.getGeneric(0).resolve();
```

Comment: There is no such method `ResolvableType::forClass`.

Comment: It is in the Spring repository: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/dfb7ca733ad309b35040e0027fb7a2f10f3a196a/spring-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/core/ResolvableTypeTests.java

Comment: Both `ResolvableType::forClass` requires `Class<?>` as their params. There's no such method that accept a Class and a `T` instance (`this`).